# Why doesn't PHP code respond to a UITextField parameter in SWIFT?

Tags: php, email, swift2, xcode7, nsmutableurlrequest

Why are my parameters `vistor_name` and `vistor_email` not transporting through PHP?

When received the body looks like this:

```
Name: 
Email:
```

This is my SWIFT code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ageField: UITextField!
@IBAction func sendButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        sendToPhp()
    }

func sendToPhp () {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let urlString = "http://sitename.com/fromswift.php"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let parameter: NSString = NSString(string: "visitor_name=\(nameField.text), visitor_email=\(ageField.text)")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = parameter.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            print("done, error: \(error)")
        }

        print(bodyData)

    }
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['visitor_name'] ."\n"
     .'Email: ' .$_POST['visitor_email'] ."\n"
    mail('blablabla@domain.com', 'FeedBack from: me', $msg);
?>
```

Comment: Can you try $msg = var_export($_POST, true); - this will show what (if any) variables are being posted. If it's empty you may need to add:  request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Comment: @Goat Master I tried and it was empty. I added : 'request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")' still the same nothing happen

Comment: Your parameter string needs to include quotation marks around the `UITextField` variables: `visitor_name=\"\(nameField.text)\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to start the task. And I guess thats the reason..Try like follows.

```
               let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response ,error ) in
                    if let response = response {

                    }
                })
                task.resume()
```

You can refer to the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/index.html) for more information.

Hope it helps. Regards.